# Katalon Studio fails to launch on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, not sure why

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, katalon-studio

I can't launch Katalon Studio from ubuntu and it gives me an error. <del>I cant see any logs in the path mentioned. I've navigated to it through the terminal and by the file manager and it is empty. Any ideas as to what is going on here?</del>

<del>Any thoughts/resources to figure out what error or what kind of errors it could be?</del>

I downloaded the latest version of java from oracle [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). I had open JDK. Thought that could maybe be the problem, but that wasn't it. Let me know what you guys think.

error from trying to launch studio:
[image]

error from log file:

```
!SESSION 2018-12-26 13:21:47.986 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=10.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -data config

!ENTRY com.kms.katalon 4 0 2018-12-26 13:21:49.019
!MESSAGE [SCR] Component definition XMLs not found in bundle com.kms.katalon. The component header value is OSGI-INF/component.xml

!ENTRY com.kms.katalon 4 0 2018-12-26 13:21:49.019
!MESSAGE [SCR] Component definition XMLs not found in bundle com.kms.katalon. The component header value is OSGI-INF/component.xml

!ENTRY com.kms.katalon 4 0 2018-12-26 13:21:49.380
!MESSAGE [SCR] Component definition XMLs not found in bundle com.kms.katalon. The component header value is OSGI-INF/component.xml

!ENTRY com.kms.katalon 4 0 2018-12-26 13:21:49.380
!MESSAGE [SCR] Component definition XMLs not found in bundle com.kms.katalon. The component header value is OSGI-INF/component.xml
katalon.versionNumber=5.10.0
katalon.buildNumber=1

Wed Dec 26 13:21:51 CST 2018

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-12-26 13:21:51.463
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException
    at com.kms.katalon.logging.LogUtil$1.call(LogUtil.java:46)
    at com.kms.katalon.logging.LogUtil.logSync(LogUtil.java:88)
    at com.kms.katalon.logging.LogUtil.writeError(LogUtil.java:34)
    at com.kms.katalon.logging.LogUtil.logError(LogUtil.java:65)
    at com.kms.katalon.logging.LogUtil.logError(LogUtil.java:28)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.application.Application.internalRunGUI(Application.java:122)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.application.Application.runGUI(Application.java:105)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.application.Application.start(Application.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:711)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 21 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-12-26 13:21:51.469
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:903)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: @Paul T. thanks for suggested edit!

Comment: I don't know about Ubuntu and the user privileges, but I seem to remember an error like this when I tried running KS on Windows 10 with a user without the administrative rights.

Comment: i tried running Katalon with: sudo ./katalon but that had no discernible difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. It seems that Katalon Studio wants a specific version of openjdk. Not the newest version. Their documentation on the subject seems pretty buried when compared to MacOS/Windows installation instructions. The linux version is in beta. After uninstalling all jres/jdks, I referred to the following:
https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/katalon-studio-gui-beta-for-linux.html

openJDK 11 didn't work but openJDK 8 worked just fine. Hopefully they make it work with other versions eventually. Appreciate all the help I got from all of you!

Answer (score 0):

The log file might be hidden, could you try to get it?
http://www.lostsaloon.com/technology/how-to-show-hidden-files-in-linux/

Comment: I was able to see hidden files after looking at that. ctrl + h in file manager or ls -a in terminal. Thank you! Updated my issue because of you! Much appreciated!